# Testflight Error when downloading app

Tags: ios, testflight

i am getting the following error when trying to download app on a iOS 7 device. What could be wrong.

"This build does not list this device as a permitted device."

Comment: please help.... its little urgent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the devices, UDID into your iOS Provisioning Profile on the apple developer site, then you need to also add that device in TestFlight and resend the build after it has been built with the updated Provisioning Profile.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you attached a new device to TestFlight after the app was built for the older set of devices. The app does not have your new device's profile in it.

To fix, you would build the app again so the new device info is in the app.

Comment: fine... ill just try your method and come back

Comment: the UDID is there in provision profile and in Testflight also. still the same error

Comment: any other suggestions?

Comment: did you look here?
http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/829651-device-not-able-to-install-build-what-do-i-do-

Comment: yes ... the device was assigned to a different person, but i did "Change Ownsership" and then installed the provision profiles. I hope its the same thing.

Comment: hmmm... could you update your original question with more details? Such as: was testflight working in iOS 6? On another device? The device had another Testflight account on it?